# Right align text in a cell table, but adding a 'variable' padding right to create space from table borders

Tags: html, css

I have a table with some columns that contain prices. I added currency with generated content and in order to better encolumn numbers, I jusitfy text of these cells to right.

*My problem is that I would also like to add some "space" from right to not have numbers too much narrow to table borders.*

Columns have different width and can contain different dinamically created numbers, so I tried to use % for padding values but results is not so good.

In **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3jyu9/)** you can see actual look of table.

Aligning of prices is made with these rules:

```
td.cella-prezzo {
    padding-right: 6%;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I thought that paddign was referred to cell width, not table width, so I tried to set padding-right:50% but is too much.

*What I would like to obtain is simply right align prices, about at center of their own column not depending by effective column width.*

For example, visually speaking, desidered result is very similar to that contained in "Costo Pers./Notte [B]" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply the padding to the element inside the cell instead:

```
td.cella-prezzo span {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 16%;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will make the percentage calculation based on the cell width instead of the whole table.
Note: I have added `display: block` only to keep the changes minimal; it would be better to replace span with div in the html code instead.